# Saltar la primera linea de un archivo csv en java

Tags: java, poo, csv, objeto

Tengo este método para leer un archivo csv y funciona perfectamente, el problema es que no encuentro la forma de saltarme la primera linea del archivo, que solo es un encabezado.

```
    public static void prueba1(){
System.out.println("Write the direction of the File:");
    
    Scanner read = new Scanner(System.in);
    String path = read.nextLine();
    read.useDelimiter("[,\n]");
    String line = "";
    try {
        FileReader leer_archivo = new FileReader(path);
        BufferedReader bufferdefault = new BufferedReader(leer_archivo);
        while ((line = bufferdefault.readLine()) != null) {
            //Ahora necesito deshacerme de la primera linea
            String[] valores = line.split(",");
            storage.Guardarpkm(Integer.parseInt(valores[0]),valores[1],valores[2],Double.parseDouble(valores[3]),Double.parseDouble(valores[4]),valores[5].equals("capturado"),valores[6].equals("vivo"));
            System.out.println("[" + valores[0] + "]" + "[" + valores[1] + "]" + "[" + valores[2] + "]" + "[" + valores[3] + "]" + "[" + valores[4] + "]" + "[" + valores[5] + "]" + "[" + valores[6] + "]");
       
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.err.println("Error");
        System.err.println(e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Puedes usar una variable auxiliar para saber si ya procesaste la primera línea del CSV.

```
....
boolean esPrimeraLinea = true;
while ((line = bufferdefault.readLine()) != null) {
        //Si es la primera línea, continuamos con la siguiente
        if (esPrimeraLinea) {
            esPrimeraLinea = false;
            continue;
        }

        // Si llegamos hasta acá, es porque ya procesamos la primera línea
      
        String[] valores = line.split(",");

        ...
```

Comment: O si **siempre** quiere saltarla, basta con poner `bufferdefault.readLine();` ***ANTES*** del while, así ya entrará al while estando en la línea que le interesa.

Comment: También funciona